# How can I make my carousel auto play until a user interacts with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, the carousel does nothing unless a user interacts with it via the left or right arrows underneath the image container. I'm trying to add a function that will cause the slides to automatically flick through UNTIL a user interacts with these arrows, upon which, this function will stop.

Here is my current code that allows the user to scroll through the slides:

```
//Next Arrow Functionality
    $('.arrow-next').click(function (e) {

        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var nextDot = currentDot.next();

        if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
            nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(1000).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        nextDot.addClass('active-dot');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //Previous Arrow Click Functionality
    $('.arrow-prev').click(function (e) {

        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

        if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
            prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
            prevDot = $('.dot').last();
        }


        currentSlide.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(1000).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by extracting out the functions to change slide.

```
function nextSlide () {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(1000).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
}

function prevSlide () {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
        prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
        prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }


    currentSlide.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(1000).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
}
```

Also create a new variable to keep track of if the user has interacted yet.

```
var userHasInteracted = false;
```

Then refactor the click handlers to use the newly created functions, and set the variable.

```
$('.arrow-next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    userHasInteracted = true;
    nextSlide();
});
$('.arrow-prev').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    userHasInteracted = true;
    prevSlide();
});
```

Then add the logic to automatically advance the slide.

```
function autoAdvance () {

    // Stop the loop if the user has interacted
    if (userHasInteracted) return ;

    // Jump to the next slide
    nextSlide();

    // Run me again in 8 seconds
    setTimeout(autoAdvance, 8000);
}

// Advance the slide in 8 seconds
setTimeout(autoAdvance, 8000);
```

Comment: You are a wizard, thank you for detailing this in a way I can understand what is happening. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help :) If you want to have a little challenge and improve your code further; try to refactor `nextSlide` and `prevSlide` into one function. The have very many lines in common and it should be quite straight forward.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll look into doing that. The site is nearly finished and refactoring is the next task. :)